# StackExchange.Redis.Extensions.Newtonsoft: High time between the calls

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

I'm using Redis and I have some problems
The time between the calls have some discrepancy
On some calls I have 1ms~2ms~3ms followed by a call that have 15ms~30ms~65ms.
It's normal?

Comment: Sometimes when I look outside from the window I see 1 or 2 people, followed by 15 or 30. Is it normal? Similarly to my silly association, your Redis integration introduces a large number of factors - infrastructure, application, other system components ... Understanding these dependencies and their relative impact on response time will allow you to better tune/use the system

Comment: My Redis and application are running on Kubernetes containers and I'm using Simple Injector to do the IoC on a AspNet Core API. I would like to know what elements can directly impact the response time of Redis.